# How lock works for update query using composite key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Wondering how locks work for update query on composite key in MySql?

Example: If a table A has composite key a1 & a2

```
a1    |   a2    |  a3
1     |   a     |  10
1     |   b     |  11
1     |   c     |  12
2     |   a     |  20
2     |   b     |  21
```

If we execute a query `UPDATE TABLE A SET a3 = 30 WHERE a1 = 1 AND a2 = a`  Then 1 row or 4 rows would acquire LOCK ?

Comment: I tried this and I can see 4 locks in mysql workbench. Can't able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick experiment shows that only one row gets locked in this case. 
I tested it with a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `lock_tst` (
    `k1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `k2` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `f1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`k1`, `k2`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And locking statements like these:

```
select * from test.lock_tst where k1=1 and k2=42 for update;
```

It should also be noted that there is no guarantee that MySQL will always lock the minimum possible rows.